# Grep -m 1 doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I'm using the following command to parse a form element from HTML using `grep`. The `$RESP` variable contains the output from a previous `curl` request ...

```
echo $RESP | grep -m 1 -o -E 'name="id" value="([A-Za-z0-9]+)"'
```

It works, except it gets every instance of `name="id"`. There's more than one instance of the form element on the page.

I tried to use the `-m 1` on `grep` to stop at the first match, but it still returns them all.

Am I doing something wrong? I can get it working with:

```
echo $RESP | grep -m 1 -o -E 'name="id" value="([A-Za-z0-9]+)"' | head -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f4
```

But, I still can't understand why `-m 1` isn't working.

Example input ...

```
<html>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4234235325">
    ...
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4234235325">
    ...
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4234235325">
</html>
```

Expected output:

```
ID: 4234235325
```

As already mentioned, the form element is repeated numerous times throughout the HTML. Whether that's poor coding, or optimisation, I don't know. But the server isn't controlled by me.

Comment: You could use the -o switch to print out every match on a new line, even if one line contains multiple matches. Then filter out with head -n 1 perhaps?

Comment: have you tried substituting `--max-count=NUM ?` At least in my man page for grep, it's listed as alternative. Also, try to remove space between m and 1

Comment: @Xieerqi yes, I tried those to no avail

Comment: Please provide a sample of input and desire output.

Comment: can you put your html?

Comment: I think the easier solution is to switch to Python because I'm finding too many issues I have to work around with bash scripting for this task.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh no. The data is sensitive.

Comment: Edited with sample data.

Comment: @LOLKAT: Maybe `grep` saw your input as one line instead of many lines. Remember `-m` stop after the first line match, not the first match.

Comment: LOLKAT do you want the output to be exactly `ID: 4234235325` or just to print the line with the value of this id? My `grep (GNU grep) 2.16` prints only matched part of the first line with your expression, so believe it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By omiting the all-important quotes around the expansion of the RESP variable, you told the shell to tear the data apart on whitespace, try to modify the data by injecting filenames, then put it together into a single line before passing it to grep. That's why `grep -m1` is giving you all the matches; it's giving you the matches for the first matching line, which happens to be all of them since it's all just one line.

```
$ var=$'hello\nworld';
$ echo $var
hello world
$ echo "$var"
hello
world
$ echo $var | grep -m1 -o '.o'
lo
wo
$ echo "$var" | grep -m1 -o '.o'
lo
```

So quote the expansion. `echo "$RESP" | grep ...`. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments

That said, `grep`, `head` and `cut` are far from the right tools for the job. Use an xml parser to parse xml. Otherwise you risk summoning the [pony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Generally yes I agree that HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex. Usually I will use Python and PyQuery, or BeautifulSoup but in this instance all I needed was a simple bash script for a single task where all I had was a terminal with limited permissions. Thank you anyway :D